# Latency in Redis GET/HGET/PUT operations etc while rdb save in on

Tags: redis, latency

My redis instance takes around 9-10 seconds to take the rdb snapshot, the snapshot happens after 60 seconds and during this time all the redis operations slow down on the similar lines.
The RDB file is 450MB only. 
Redis server version 2.8
What could be the reason for the same and how can it be fixed ?

Comment: What are the server's specs? How much RAM does Redis use?

Comment: It is using 1.5G of RAM, it is a machine with 32G RAM. What else do you want to know  ?

Comment: How much free RAM is there and how fast is the storage?

Comment: Free is about 5-6 GB and disk utilization usually stays 1-2% but when bg save is happening it reaches to 40% for a second.

Comment: Given the amount of free RAM, it sounds like whatever else is on that server besides Redis may be causing this.

Comment: It might be , thanks for helping.